# Inverse Fourier Transform for $e^{-a/f}$ and $e^{-a/\sqrt{f}}$

Tags: fourier-transform

How do we solve for the inverse Fourier Transform for the following two functions?

$$X(f) = e^{-a/f}$$

$$X(f) = e^{-a/\sqrt{f}}$$

Comment: uhm, you got problems as $f \to 0$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes we need to omit $f=0$....that said....

Comment: (The FT of x= 1 also goes to infinity, yet that doesn't stop us)